# Always selecting at a certain position based on

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

I'm trying to make it so when you hit the Select button, it always alerts whatever the the blue highlighted div is over.  How do I make it so it is always the case that the item under the blue is selected?

In the picture's case, it would alert "stale" if it works how I ideally am trying to get it to work

This is what I have right now, and it doesn't alert anythings

```
$('#selectButton').click( function() {
    alert($('#myAdjSelect option:selected').val());
});
```

And the code for the lists is as follows

```
<div class="control-group">
          <div class="controls">
            <div style="width:540px;height:16px;border:2px solid blue;position:absolute;margin-top:38px;background-color:rgba(0,0,255,.3)"></div>
            <select multiple="multiple" id="myAdjSelect" class="input-xlarge" style="height:100px">
            </select>
            <select multiple="multiple" id="myNounSelect" class="input-xlarge" style="height:100px">
            </select>

            <button type="button" id="selectButton" name="selectButton" class="btn btn-primary">Select</button>
          </div>
        </div>
```

I am trying to get it to select without having to click, any ideas on how I might accomplish this?

Comment: Positioning the blue `div` over the select elements does not select any options within the select menu.  Is there something else going on with JavaScript that you have not shown?

Comment: I'm aware it doesn't.  That's the problem I'm trying to solve and I'm looking for a direction to go to that might help me solve that.  Because frankly I'm stumped and have no idea how I would even start to trying to figure that out.

Comment: You want to be able to select items from the menu without actually clicking on them, just by passing the mouse over it and then pressing the Select button?

Comment: Are you trying to use the blue box to indicate which item is selected in the adjective menu and in the noun menu? I guess you need two blue boxes...

Comment: Yes, I am trying to use the blue box to indicate which item is selected in the two boxes.  So if the user hits the select button, whatever words the blue div box is over the words will be selected.

Basically, I am trying to get the third item that is being shown to always be the one selected

Comment: BUT since you have two menus, you need two  blue boxes, one for the left menu and one for the right.

Comment: Sounds like you need a `mousein` handler that adds a highlight class to the option the mouse is over, and removes it from all the sibling options. But it seems like this will be a very difficult UI to use, since the mouse will often pass over the right menu while the user is moving from the left menu to the button.

Comment: What you are asking for is how to design a custom UI widget.  Maybe the jquery UI library has something.  Regardless, this post does not lend itself to a simple question that can be answered in a few minutes.  You need to do a bit more research to see if there is JavaScript code or frameworks that have something like what you envision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll need to briefly hide the blue overlay div, and get the element under the div.
if you give the overlay div a class or id this would be a bit easier.

```
$('#selectButton').click( function() {

    var overlay = $('#overlayDiv');
    var pos = overlay.position();

    overlay.hide();
    element = document.elementFromPoint( pos.left + 5, pos.top + 5 );
    overlay.show();

    alert($(element).val());

});
```

We've added a bit to the position to make sure we're inside the overlay. Rather than using a margin to position the overlay, you may be better off using the `top` property. If you want the element from the second select list, add an offset to the left position and fetch that element in the same manner. http://jsfiddle.net/bLpgL/

Comment: Hmmm so I'm trying to get this to work, I change `pos.left()` and `pos.top()` to `pos.left` and `pos.top` as I was getting an error.  But now the alert is blank.  I alerted `element` and got found it was an `[object HTMLDivElement]` but I'm not exactly sure how to play with that, looking it up now though.

Comment: sorry, yah, I always forget and call .left as a function rather than a property. I've fiddled it for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/bLpgL/ ... `element` is a DOM element. You can use it as a selector in jquery using $(element)

Answer (score 3):

First of all change

```
alert($('#myAdjSelect option:selected').text());
```

to

```
alert($('#myAdjSelect option:selected').val());
```

If you want to get the event even when a different event happened, you could use `.focus()`